# Can't read from XML file in S3 with Python

Tags: python, xml, amazon-s3

I have an XML file sitting in S3 and I need to open it from a lambda function and write strings to a DynamoDB table. I am using `etree` to parse the file. However, I don't think any content is actually getting read from the file. Below is my code, the error, and some sample xml.

**Code:**

```
import boto3
import lxml
from lxml import etree

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = 'Lambda ran successfully!'
    return output

def WriteItemToTable():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    obj = s3.Object('bucket', 'object')
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()

    image_id = etree.fromstring(body.content).find('.//IMAGE_ID').text
    print(image_id)


WriteItemToTable()
```

**Error:**

```
'str' object has no attribute 'content'
```

**XML:**

```
 <HOST_LIST>
    <HOST>
      <IP network_id="X">IP</IP>
      <TRACKING_METHOD>EC2</TRACKING_METHOD>
      <DNS><![CDATA[i-xxxxxxxxxx]]></DNS>
      <EC2_INSTANCE_ID><![CDATA[i-xxxxxxxxx]]></EC2_INSTANCE_ID>
      <EC2_INFO>
        <PUBLIC_DNS_NAME><![CDATA[xxxxxxxxxxxx]]></PUBLIC_DNS_NAME>
        <IMAGE_ID><![CDATA[ami-xxxxxxx]]></IMAGE_ID>
```

I am trying to pull the AMI ID inside of the `<IMAGE_ID>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is read, what you get is just an attribute error. `body` is already a string and it has no `content` attribute. Instead of `fromstring(body.content)` just do `fromstring(body)`.

Comment: This worked, thank you. However, it only prints one AMI ID, and there are several `<IMAGE_ID>` tags with different AMI values. I think it finds the first tag and exits. How would I get the rest?

Comment: Use `.findall` instead of `.find`.

Comment: This worked, but since `findall()` returns elements as a list, I had to iterate with a `for loop`.